# Heroku Scheduler for recurring tasks and Delayed Jobs for asynchronous tasks, all using one web dyno

Tags: heroku, asynchronous, ruby-on-rails-4, background-process, delayed-job

Very similar question to [Is it feasible to run multiple processeses on a Heroku dyno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279527/is-it-feasible-to-run-multiple-processeses-on-a-heroku-dyno), or [Running Heroku background tasks with only 1 web dyno and 0 worker dynos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634447/running-heroku-background-tasks-with-only-1-web-dyno-and-0-worker-dynos) except I'm talking about a Ruby on Rails app.

**Context:**

I understand that it's encouraged to separate worker and web dynos... but I'm still testing and don't want to pay the expense. Especially because with my app, all the web requests pretty much happen either in the AM or in the PM, and during the whole middle of the day (and also middle of the night), literally nothing is happening.

I'd like the web dyno to run two types of background processing on the "downtime":

1. A recurring, long-running task every day (mailings)
2. An asynchronous, long-running task that is triggered when a user performs a certain action (it's a mailer)

I've done quite a bit of reading on this, but this is my first time doing anything asynchronous, so I wanted to ask the community a couple of questions just to ensure what I'm trying to do is feasible.

**Questions**

**How do I do activity #1 for free?** 
To put it bluntly... considering my context above, if I use Heroku's Scheduler add-on, this runs a one-off dyno which I'll be charged for since I use NewRelic now to constantly ping my web dyno so it never actually sleeps meaning my one web dyno is my free dyno. Is there another way of doing this with the one web dyno that, in the middle of the night, won't be processing any requests? Alternatively, is there a way to tell New Relic to ping except at certain times, which will also then allow me to spin up a one-off dyno but still be within my free dyno hours?

**For activity #2, I'm thinking of using Delayed Jobs, but how do I tell Delayed Jobs to delay until end of user 1's session, and then run mailer for user 1, but then pause again if user 2 sends a request, and then when user 2 is finished, start where left off on user 1's mailer, and then do user 2's mailer... and so forth?**  I think the root of the challenge here is that from what I've read, Delayed Jobs needs to be started with a script. But I'm not going to be at my computer starting a script all the time. How do I make the start (and the queue as illustrated in the question) something that happens automatically?

Would love even just point me directional pointers on what methods/ what considerations, etc.

Comment: Instead of spending lots of time trying to work around well defined limits *(ie. Heroku's 30s request timeout)*, why not do things the right way? I suggest a service like http://hirefire.io/, particularly if you're concerned about keeping the cost of your workers/dynos to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to check out a nifty gem https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch to do this. According to the author, it was written specifically to use Heroku's single dyno for hobby websites that have no need to spin up another dyno. It basically creates another thread.

FYI also, there is an add-on link that allows sucker_punch to do recurring tasks, called https://github.com/facto/fist_of_fury

Comment: Make sure you monitor the memory usage though so your dyno doesn't start to swap memory to disk which will make it incredibly slow. The memory usage is written to the log regularly and errors are raised in the log as well when the max memory is reached.